# Navigation of html forms (hide() and Show() ) Via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#gotoStep2").click(function(){
            $("#form1").hide();
            $("#form2").show();
        });

        $("#gotoStep3").click(function(){
            $("#form1").hide();
            $("#form2").hide();
            $("#form3").show();
        });
});
```

Here I have 3 forms, which i want to visit one by one. When i click **gotoStep2** i am able to reach the 2nd form, but when i click **gotoStep3** the page is getting redirected to form1, followed by just a second flash of form3.
Need Suggestions!

Navigation is 
form1 -> form2 -> form 3

Comment: HTML: http://pastie.org/pastes/8614451/text
CSS: 
#form2, #form3 {
    display: none;
}

Comment: It would be helpful to just post the relevant HTML in your question, or create a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that we can use.

Comment: No need to hide form 1 again if it's already hidden